# Loading an image from an URL into Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-drawable

This is the code below which i am using.

**mMap** is the instance of GoogleMap

my question is how can i load **URL** of the image instead of **R.drawable.ic_map_barber**

I spend my lot of time but not getting any solution. please help me to solve this problem

```
DrawMarker.getInstance(getActivity()).draw(mMap, new LatLng(lat, Long), R.drawable.ic_map_barber, BarberName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

draw/add the marker after you obtain the bitmap :

```
URL url = new URL("http://imagepath/store/url");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```